# Mass find and replace in answers, questions and titles of questions

Tags: support, app-request, editing

### 1. Briefly

I don't find, how I can mass replace string in multiple answers, questions and titles of questions of any Stack Exchange site.

---

### 2. Example

For example, I want to replace incorrect form of a word `консоле` to correct form `консоли`. In Russian Stack Overflow at the time of writing this post we have [**278 results**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%22) for `консоле`. It would be nice, if would be possible mass find and replace, even if regular expressions will not supported.

---

### 3. Not helped

1. I could not find answer for my task in Google, Stack Apps and Meta Stack Exchange sites.

---

### 4. Notes

1. Yes, I understand, that before mass edits I need to ask Russian Stack Overflow community in [**Meta**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/).
2. In Russian we don't have word or form of a word `консоле`. In several cases word `консоль` [**have a form `консоли`**](http://morpher.ru/Demo.aspx?s=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C).

Comment: This is doable but rather involved (more of a project than a quick answer).  I estimate that it would take me a week to code to something beta-releasable. Good luck.